# Div element not showing up on page, even after inspect element

Tags: html, invisible

I have a site, which should be suited for mobile and pc, but i haven't added the latter one in yet. the problem is, I have two  tags with class="row", but only the first shows up (after you make the page small enough). code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="api/reponse-api-2.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
</head>
<body class="nomargin">
    <!--MOBILE VERSION-->
    <div class="size-small">
        <div class="row"><iframe frameBorder="0" src="html/header-small.html" class="col-12" height="100px"/></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 checkbox-mobile">
                <form>
                <input type="checkbox">Embed site in browser</input>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--TABLET VERSION-->
    <div class="size-medium">
        tablet
    </div>

    <!--PC VERSION-->
    <div class="size-large">
        pc
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please share your CSS files

Comment: The problem is not with displaying, because if I click "Inspect Element", it doesn't show up either. (see title)

Comment: PieterMantel Your issue is with html syntax please see the below answer by @Roy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error syntaxis HTML:

```
<div class="size-small">
       <!-- The iframe must be closed </iframe> -->
       <!-- (if bootstrap) The class col-12 is col-sm-12 or col-md-12 or col-xs-12 (NOT col-12)  -->
        <div class="row"><iframe frameBorder="0" src="html/header-small.html" class="col-12" height="100px"></iframe></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 checkbox-mobile">
                <form>
                <!-- The input close is wrong. -->
                <!-- <input type="checkbox">BAD</input> -->
                     <input type="checkbox">GOOD
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Just adding the comment for the answer to be a little easier to understand. Iframes don't self close so you need to actually include </iframe> and secondly checkbox type inputs do not close.  Both are issues here however the iframe one was causing issues with your closing tag for the <div class="row"> that was not displaying.

Comment: oh ok thanks! i do not use bootstrap but my own responsive api, because I thought bootstrap added to much nonsense.